# Avoiding an infinite while loop

Tags: c, while-loop, user-input, infinite-loop

I'm stuck on a while loop exercise. The program seems to work fine as long as I only enter integers. However, if I enter a character, a symbol or a real number with decimals (even integers such as 1.0), I get a infinite loop.

```
int main() 
{
    int num;
    printf("Enter an odd number 1 and 10.");
    while(1) 
       {
        printf("\n\nEnter : ");
        scanf("%d", &num);

        if(num == 0)
            break;
        else if(num < 0 || num > 10)
            printf("You entered number is beyond the range.");
        else if(num % 2 == 0)
            printf("You entered an even number.");
        else
            printf("You entered a correct number.");
       }

   printf("You are exiting the program.");      
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check the result of scanf.

Comment: `num` isn't changed if input is incorrect.

Comment: @Fabio_MO there is a conditional break!!

Answer (score 0):

*However, if I enter a character, a symbol or a real number with decimals ?*  Then you have **undefined behaviour** as `scanf()` expecting `int` argument but you are providing other than `int` argument.

*even integers such as `1.0` ?* No, `1.0` is not an `integer` it's a real number.

Check the return value of `scanf()` to know whether it's success or fail. Open `man 3 scanf` and analyze. For e.g

`int ret = 0;`

`ret = scanf("%d",&num);`

`if(ret != 1) {
  /* Error handling */
 }`

Comment: I appreciate your help. Your method was simple yet it works perfectly. Thanks again!